# Multiple entities sharing the same role relationship table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, domain-driven-design, dns

Trying to adhere to DRY principles, would the following be a valid way of having multiple objects share a common role relationship table.

If we have the following types (created purely for this example):

```
class User
{
    ...
}

class Article
{
    ...
}
```

Both of these objects need to have roles defined against them. As such, Role is not unique to any of these objects.

My idea was to have Repositories perform CRUD operations on these objects, but also to let Role have it's own Repository perhaps accessed via a service?

Repositories would feed out UserDTO and ArticleDTO to a Builder class which would produce the necessary Domain objects. In this case:

```
class User
{
    ...
    IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    //Other Domain objs/logic
}

class Article
{
    ...
    IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    //Other Domain objs/logic
}
```

Role object would have a Role table:

ID Name

And a relationship table:

itemId roleId itemType

the role builder/service used to attach roles to the domain object could perhaps look something like this:

```
static class RoleBuilder
{
    IEnumerable<Role> Fetch(int id, typeof(obj))
    {
        //fetch from RoleRep
    }

    bool Save(IEnumerable<Role>, int id, typeof(obj))
    {
        //save through role rep
    }
}
```

Is there anything inherently wrong with this idea? e.g:

```
public static UserBuilder
{
    public User FetchUser(int id)
    {
        //map userDTO to user
        var user = map...

        //populate roles
        if(user != null)
            user.Roles = RoleBuilder.Fetch(id, typeof(user));
    }
}
```

The alternative is to have User and Article manage their own Role manipulation and perhaps have multiple role relationship tables e.g. user_has_roles, article_has_roles

The first solution would allow roles to be modified by the end user too (renamed, new roles added etc) without corrupting the domain model whereas in the second solution, i'm not sure how to do that cleanly (update them through user, through article?)

Comment: Looks like a lot of effort for tracking 'roles', with little to no behavior associated with them. Also, technically speaking, it would be more appropriate to say that both User and Article have the role 'IHaveRoles' or 'HasRoles' (how's that for a naming conflict). If 'roles' are truely a separate concept, it might be worth exploring whether they belong in the same bounded context.

Comment: Thanks Yves! I had a bit of a think about the structure of my original suggestion and have changed it quite a bit. I'll perhaps post an Update for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the concept of Roles is separate from User and Articles - which it sounds like it is since it applies to both of those domain objects - then I would probably model is separately like you suggest.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "allow roles to be modified by the end user too".  If roles are a separate concept they should probably have their own domain classes to represent the operations that can be performed against roles (rename, delete, etc).

Also your code snippet should probably look like this (using generics instead of the invalid typeof() syntax in your above snippet):

```
static class RoleBuilder {
    static IEnumerable<Role> Fetch<T>(int id) {
        switch(typeof(T)) { ... }
    }

    static bool Save<T>(IEnumerable<Role> roles, int id) {
        switch(typeof(T)) { ... }
    }
}
```

I would probably also consider having some sort of base class for all the domain objects which can have roles assigned (if roles are used for security then maybe SecurableEntity or something), then you can have a base class table in the DB to support a shared identities for ID's (so that you can get rid of the itemType column in the Roles table).  Alternatively, you could just use GUID's for the entity ID's, which makes alot of things much easier.

Comment: Hi Dylan, "allow roles to be modified by the end user too", by this I meant there will be a form in the UI which would allows Admins (or assigned roles) to update the roles within the system.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea sounds good. I'd avoid to couple roles (or more general some authorization system) to articles and user models.

What I don't like about your code is the static RoleBuilder. First: it's static and that leads to coupling. Second: The RoleBuilder should not retrieve anything from a repository but get  somes instance *pushed* in by some service for example and build roles model or just a list from this data. In case you let the RoleBuilder query the Repo you couple the responsibility of the Builder with the querying logic.

Another problem could arise from your UserBuilder implementation. For fetching a single user that might be ok but fetching multiple users with that logic will lead to a Select N+1.

Answer (score 0):

Your second idea of multiple relationship tables is more appropriate. You will not be able to maintain a clean foreign key in your database with the first method.  You should be able to update the Role from either entity and it will be reflected in the next get from the repository for the other entity. In my opinion it is usually best to leave referential integrity up the database, and with both join tables having a foreign key to the roles table it will prevent you from doing things like deleting a role from the user entity when it is attached to the Article Entity. Although the first solution is clever, you will have to implement some business logic to ensure data integrity... why clutter your business layer with this kind of thing when the ORM can do it for you?